# vue app using amplify auth: edit cognito userpool app client refresh token expiry time issue

Tags: vue.js, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, refresh-token

I have a working Vue app using Amplify Authentication. I would like to change the expiration time of the JWT tokens (access, Id and refresh).

I edited these settings in the userpool app client settings to the following:

1. refresh token – 60 minutes
2. access token – 5 minutes
3. id token – 5 minutes

These settings have no affect when I test the app. The refresh token indicates that it expires after 24 hours (which I presume is the default expiry time set on installation/configuration)

What do I need to do to change the expiration times for these tokens?

Thanks

Comment: Have you cleared your cookies and logged back in?

Comment: hi @Nick K9, yes i have

Comment: Does [this caveat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html) apply to your situation? "When your user signs in with the hosted UI or a federated identity provider (IdP), Amazon Cognito sets session cookies that are valid for 1 hour. If you use the hosted UI or federation, and specify a minimum duration of less than 1 hour for your access and ID tokens, your users will still have a valid session until the cookie expires."

Comment: hi @NickK9 no i'm using my own UI and call the authentication api's manually

Comment: hi @NickK9 - after using it for a while now, i can conclude that the user is logged out after 1 hour - which is what i wanted (as per my user pool settings) but the refresh token still indicates that it expires after 24 hours!